# How to loop through the files extracted by a find command and pass is as input to another command?

Tags: shell-script, shell

```
find . -name 'Email*.log' -exec grep -il 'bad password' {} \;| while read line; do
  TEMPNUM=`tail -20 $line | grep 'bad password' | wc -l`
  if [ $TEMPNUM -gt 0 ]; then
     awk '/Username/{print $NF}' $line >> expiredmailbox.txt
  fi
done
```

This is the code I used and ran the shell script. I am getting
line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
Even if just try to echo the $line. I am getting an error. How can I eliminate this?

Comment: hmm the syntax looks ok - your script seems to work for me apart from the `awk` (works if I replace with `echo "$line"`) (you probably want to add a `-type f` to your `find` command to stop `grep` throwing errors and quote your `"$line"` variable but I don't think those things are your problem). Are you sure you copied your script here exactly??

Comment: In which shell you are working, is it perhaps `bash`? Assuming you need loops at all it would make things quite a bit easier.

Comment: Maybe these links may be useful: [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and [why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)

Answer (score -1):

can you try this..

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -name 'Email*.log' | xargs grep -li  'bad password' |  while read line
do
  TEMPNUM=$(tail -20 "${line}" | grep -c 'bad password')
  if [ "${TEMPNUM}" -gt "0" ]; then
     awk '/Username/{print $NF}' "${line}" >> expiredmailbox.txt
  fi
done
```

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: if you run with bash -x script.sh 

what is the output.. where it shows the error ? what is your OS